# Number of questions with no answers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database, has-one

In my application I have questions and answers:

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers
end
```

Each question has a column called `answers_count` that stores the amount of answers. 
My problem is I am unable to get the amount of questions without an answer. In my comments controller I have this (questions belong to comments):

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.find params[:id]      
  @unanswered = @comment.questions.select('comments.*, count(questions.id) as answer_count')
      .joins(:answers)
      .group('questions.id')
      .having('answer_count == 0')    
end
```

And then in my comment show view I have this:

```
 <% unless @unanswered.blank? %>
 action
 <% end %>
```

However I get this error:

```
Association named 'answers' was not found on Question; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Here are the question and answer models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :answer
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :question 
end
```

Comment: You have typed `answer_count` instead of `answers_count` in the query.

Comment: May be not. Please post your models.

Comment: Do you have a `has_many :answers` association on your `Question` model?

Comment: Since you did counter_cache for answers on questions shouldn't be just: `@comment.questions.where(answers_count: 0)` ???

Comment: Pavan and Shadwell: the question model has_many answers and the answer model belongs_to a question. @Octupus-Paul I'll see if your method works.

Comment: Please post your models to make sure you have given the correct associations.And also where is `@comment` varaible initialised?

Comment: @Octopus-Paul your method gives no errors but it still does the action even if there are no unanswered questions.

Comment: Pavan: posted the models and added to the controller where @comment is initialized.

Comment: Try to change this line `resources :answers` to `resource :answer`.

Comment: If a questions has answers_count=0 that means that there is no answer for that question so. If answers_count>0 you should have answers. I think you put the wrong condition into your view. Look at the result of the query I posted above and post the result please

Comment: And also this condition `<% unless @unanswered.blank? %>` is wrong.It should be `<% if @unanswered.present? %>`.

Comment: Sooo will you tell us what's the result of `@comment.questions.where(answers_count: 0)` ???

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is all in an 'unless @unanswered.blank?' loop because the action is an 'unanswered questions' title and i don't want it showing if there are no unanswered questions. However, @unanswered.count gives the number of questions regardless if they have answers or not.

Comment: So on one have 1 question that has an answer yet @unanswered.count is still 1.

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem. Even the questions with an answer have 0 as their answers_count. Any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

Set `has_many :answers` instead of `has_one` in `Question` and set the counter_cache option:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base 
   belongs_to :question, counter_cache: true
end
```

And then

```
@question.where('answer_count == 0')
```

If the question has only one answer than you don't need to store answer_count nor counter_cache is needed. Should be something like:

```
Question.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id')
                                           .where('answers.questions_id IS NULL')
```

Comment: Is this possible while still keeping has_one :answer? I only want one answer for each question.

Comment: You can of course. See the edit, I added the case if you need has_one

Comment: OK so 'Questions' gave me this error: 'uninitialized constant CommentsController::Questions' so I changed it to '@comment.questions.include' but that gives me this:'undefined method `include' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Question:0x00000102edee48>'

Comment: Sorry, it should be `Question`. check my edit again. I've put a better solution.

Comment: Question gives me this: undefined method `join' for #<Class:0x00000101f69e40>. @unanswered is in the comments show controller so should it not be @comment.questions? (although that gives me:undefined method `where' for "#<Question:0x00000104c994b0>":String)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is the name of the table/model answer or comment?

Comment: Answers belong_to questions and then questions belong_to comments. We are dealing with questions and answers but @unanswered is displayed on the comments show page. Hope that clears things up :)